# How to unzip file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, archive, unzip

I use `SSZipArchive`. After downloading file I want to unzip archive and show image. But code doesn’t work. How to fix it?

**download file**

```
 -(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender
    {
        if (_HighScore == 2) {

            _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link2.zip"];

            _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];

            [_downloadTask1 resume];
    }

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSURL *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/2.zip", documentsFolder]];

        NSError *error;
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:newLocation error:&error];
NSLog(@"file%@", newLocation.absoluteString);
}
```

**unzip file**

```
    _documentsDirectory1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
    _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file://%@/2.zip"];
    _fileExists1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_zipPath1 isDirectory:false];
    if( [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:_zipPath1 toDestination:_destinationPath1] != NO ) {
        NSLog(@"Dilip Success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Dilip Error");
    }
```

**UPD**

```
-(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender
{
    if (_HighScore == 2) {

        _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link2.zip"];

        _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];

        [_downloadTask1 resume];
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) {
        _documentsDirectory1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        _zipPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (downloadTask == _downloadTask1) { NSData *urlData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url1]; [urlData1 writeToFile:_zipPath1 atomically:YES];}

});
}
```

Comment: between i noticed that `[_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/PDFFolder"]` you are adding `/` actually, the method `stringByAppendingPathComponent` adds the `/` u don't need to specify it just change it to `_filePath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFFolder"];` just use `PDFFolder`, replace it for all

Comment: doesn’t work… I update question. please check.

Comment: did u check the paths and the download zip file present in the specified folder ..? and also the method to load image check the image is present in the path while u are loading the image  ` UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath1];`

Comment: How can i do  it?

Comment: If i download image (not image in zip) all works fine.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]);` add this in viewdidload and u will get the path to DocumentDirectory and check all folders and image files are present or not

Comment: all work if i use `_filePath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MediaData/FILENAME"];
    NSString *workSpacePath = [_filePath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"d1.png"];`

Comment: u should specify the path which is specify the image after downloading it creates a folder containing the image, u should specify the path for that image

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in saving zip file in `DocumentDirectory`, `_filePath1` is contain the destination folder for unzip, instead of that you need to use `filePath` that contain `zip` file name along with path, so use that like this.

```
[urlData1 writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Also it is batter if you use `writeToFile:options:error:` method so that you can know it is successfully writing `Data` or not.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.responseData writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];
```

**Edit:**
You are probably messing with something, so change your code from downloading to saving and unzipping like this.

```
-(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender
{
    if (_HighScore == 2) {
        _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"link2.zip"];  
        _downloadTask1 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            //Saved in NSDocumentDirectory
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *zipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
            [self.responseData writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];

            //UNZip
            NSString *zipPath1 = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.zip"];
            NSString *destinationPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",path];
            [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath1 toDestination:destinationPath];
            //Now access the content of zip
        }]; 
        [_downloadTask1 resume];
    }   
}
```

Comment: I update question. please check. in debug I get `NSLog(@«Dilip Success»);` but image doesn’t appear. Why?

Comment: Sorry i have checked your previous comment, are you sure you are getting success. then what is the problem?

Comment: I download file and copy in folder `NSURL *newLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@«file://%@/2.zip», documentsFolder]];`(all works fine)  but in **unzip file** my path in folder wrong. How to specify correct path in folder?

Comment: I don’t know what path to folder I should give. How to look correct path to folder?

Comment: Currently i don't have mac will help you answer tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I will be waiting

Comment: Please show me the code of this `[self.responseData writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];`

Comment: If you are using simulator goto the document directory and check your zip is  saved successfully

Comment: Yes. Zip saved successfully in Library/Caches/2.zip

Comment: Means inside `/Docments/Library/Caches/2.zip` right?

Comment: not. `/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/49CA6F72-C56F-4A95-85EB-AF98F1E5FDC9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B54F8B7B-1EDB-4DB2-BD8F-1748713CBC85/Library/Caches/2.zip`

Comment: @User That was your problem when you saving zip you have used `NSCachesDirectory` and for unzipping you are giving path for  `NSDocumentDirectory` how is going to possible, so simply use either `NSCachesDirectory` or `NSDocumentDirectory` both the times. I personally prefer NSDocumentDirectory because in cache you lost the data.

Comment: Update question. I used code in **UPD**. But file saved twice. How to save file in `NSDocumentDirectory` once?

Comment: Can you explain What is UPD?

Comment: It is the subtitle in my question

Answer (score 0):

try like this , its work for me

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];
```

after completion of unarchive the following method will call

```
#pragma mark - Unzipp Delegate

 - (void)zipArchiveDidUnzipArchiveAtPath:(NSString *)path zipInfo:   (unz_global_info)zipInfo unzippedPath:(NSString *)unzippedPath {
       //write code here after unarchive zip file
    }
```

Comment: please check once thisline in your code _filePath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFFolder"];     and also _filePath2 = [_documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFFolder"]

Comment: try like this    _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"unzip2.zip"];

Comment: why you are giving like this file://%@/2.zip

Comment: I don’t know what path to folder I should give. How to look correct path to folder?

Comment: _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithformat@"%@"[_zipPath1 lastpathComponent]]];

Comment: I get issue Expected ']'

Comment: okay, _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithformat@"%@",[_zipPath1 lastpathComponent]]];

Comment: same issue Expected ']'

Comment: okay, _destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithformat:@"%@",[_zipPath1 lastpathComponent]]];

Comment: those are syntax issues only , i type that code here not on xcode , u can resolve by yourself.

Comment: I add `_destinationPath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @«%@«,[_zipPath1 lastPathComponent]]];` but nothing happens. File not unzipping